# Pick the other element in a Javascript array containing two

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript array like:

```
var arr = ['black', 'white'];
```

Now if I have a variable containing one of the element, how can I easily get the other? For example

```
var color = 'black';
var otherColor = '???'; // should be 'white', how can I get it?
```

I'm looking for the simplest/cleaner way possible.

Also, I don't want to mutate the original array.

Thanks

**ANSWER**

What about:

```
var otherColor = arr[1 - arr.indexOf(color)]
```

Comment: A precaution - all the solutions given below are assuming that your array will never increase/decrease in size (2 item of length).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var otherColor = arr[1 - arr.indexOf(color)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for that:

```
var arr = ['black', 'white'];
var color = 'black';
var otherColor = arr.filter(function(item){ return item !== color })[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Ternary `if` statement:

```
var otherColor = arr[0] === color ? arr[1] : arr[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

`arr.filter(x => x !== color)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ES6 solution using destructuring to throw into the mix.

```
const arr = ['black', 'white']; // our list of values.
const [black, white] = arr; // destructured into variables black and white
const color = 'black'; 
cont otherColor === black ? black : white;
```

Comment: This solution also uses a ternary. I added this for an extra solution though. It's not the simplest and by your sample you're not using ES6 anyway.